# Wildcards in jnlp template file

Tags: java, security, templates, wildcard, jnlp

Since the last security changes in Java 7u40, it is required to sign a JNLP file. This can either be  done by adding the final JNLP in **JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP**, or by providing a template JNLP in **JNLP-INF/APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP** in the signed main jar.

The first way works well, but we would like to allow to pass a previously unknown number of runtime arguments to our application.

Therefore, our APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp codebase="*">
    <information>
        <title>...</title>
        <vendor>...</vendor>
        <description>...</description>
        <offline-allowed />
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <java version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <jar href="launcher/launcher.jar" main="true"/>
        <property name="jnlp...." value="*" />
        <property name="jnlp..." value="*" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="...">
        *
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

The problem is the * inside of the *application-desc* tag.

It is possible to wildcard a fixed number of arguments using multiple *argument* tags (see code below), but then it is not possible to provide more or less arguments to the application (Java Webstart will no start with an empty *argument* tag).

```
    <application-desc main-class="...">
        <argument>*</argument>
        <argument>*</argument>
        <argument>*</argument>
    </application-desc>
```

Does someone can confirm this problem and/or has a solution for passing a previously undefined number of runtime arguments to the Java application?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can see after reading the JNLP 7 specification, it appears what you want can't be done.  The asterisk can only represent text data, not multiple XML elements.

In your situation, I would make the `main` method capable of doing its own parsing of a single argument so it can be treated as multiple values, using a custom separator.  Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 2 && args[0].equals("--args")) {
        args = args[1].split(";;");
    }

    // Continue as normal 
}
```

This allows the template to contain:

```
<application-desc main-class="com.example.app.Main">
    <argument>--args</argument>
    <argument>*</argument>
</application-desc>
```

And your the actual .jnlp file could contain something like:

```
<application-desc main-class="com.example.app.Main">
    <argument>--args</argument>
    <argument>files.txt;;29;;true;;1384212567908</argument>
</application-desc>
```

Comment: You're right this is a possible workaround, and if there is really no JNLP-only way, I will use your solution for this. Thx!